# Break while loop for particular argument

Tags: python

I am in learning stage. Trying to create algo for trading.

Have a stock list
`l = [ 's1', 's2' ]`

Getting ltp through  While Loop .
If stock s1 hit sl or target than break while loop for s1 to avoid multiple order and continue for s2 until condition not meet

```py
stock = ["s1","s2"]

def sell(stock,ltp):
    while True:
        sl = ltp  - ltp*.01
        tgt =ltp + ltp*0.01

        # getting last price from api as Ltp
        if Ltp <=sl:
            # place sell order for S1
            break

            '''how to continue getting Ltp for stock s2 until condition not meet '''

def buy():
        for stock in stock:
            # buy order at ltp
            sell(stock,ltp)
```

Comment: The `while` is inside the `sell` function which is ***already called in a loop*** for each stock in the `buy` function

Comment: `for stock in stock` is wrong.

Comment: Just a naive maths question: since sl = 99% of ltp, how do you expect `Ltp <=sl` to be true ? Or are Ltp and ltp 2 different values? And what is tgt for ? Your question is VERY confusing!

Comment: Bought 'Apple' stock 100 . Target 110 and SL 90. Bought ' Amazon ' at 200 sl 180 and target 220. How track both stocks for exit at SL or Target. If target hit in 'Apple' To avoid multiple sell orders to exchange want to stop tracking 'Apple' stock and continue with 'Amazon' stock. Until sl or target not hitting.

Comment: You could add a "stock_sold" flag (boolean) variable for each stock, set it to False before the start of the loop, add its state to the `if` selling conditions, and set it to True when the stock is sold. Also, condition the `break` to all flags being true ( something like `if all([stock_sold[stock] for stock in all_stocks]): break` )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the code based on the examples you gave in a comment; the code includes "sold" flags for each of the stock, and will sell if the Ltp (current stock price if I understood correctly) reaches buy_price - 10% (stoploss) or buy_price + 10% (target).

You could try something like this:

```
# dictionary of stock:buy price
stock = {"s1":100,"s2":200}

def sell(stock):
    # create a dictionary of status for all stocks
    stock_sold = {sto:False for sto in stock}
    while True:
        for sto in stock:
           # getting last price from api as Ltp
           if (Ltp <= stock[sto]*0.9 or Ltp >= stock[sto]*1.1) and not stock_sold[sto]:
               # place sell order for S1
               stock_sold[sto] = True

        if all([stock_sold[sto] for sto in stock]:
            break
```